# Issue with PHP Contact Form Spam

Tags: php, forms, contacts, email-spam

So recently I fixed my contact form on my website but I have a problem. People can send me emails without needing to put anything in the contact form boxes.

So pretty much people can just press the Send Button without needing to type anything which is really annoying.

Anyway to fix this?

Here is my PHP Code: https://hastebin.com/ukowawovab.pl

Here is my HTML Code: https://hastebin.com/hisayacuji.xml

Thanks!
TrifleTower

Comment: put your code here, check boxes are not empty (you seem to know you should do this), add CAPCHA

Comment: this is actually simpler than you may think. Check for empty values and use full headers

Comment: I've added my HTML code to the thread. I'm pretty new to PHP so I don't know how to check for empty values and use full headers etc.

Comment: [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments, check for any empty fields.

Even with `required` added, bots may be accessing the php file directly, or others.

```
<?php

if(!empty($_REQUEST['name'])

&& !empty($_REQUEST['email'])

&& !empty($_REQUEST['skype'])

&& !empty($_REQUEST['message'])){

 $to = "email@example.com";
 $subject = "FluxDesigns Contact Form";
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $skype = $_REQUEST['skype'];
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $body = " Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Skype: $skype \n Message: $message \n\n IP Address: $ip";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   header('Location: /thanks');
   exit; // added that to prevent further execution
  }

 }
 else{
     echo "Fill in all fields";

     }
```

You could additionally add a checkbox and check if it is set with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and handle it accordingly.

However, you should use full headers as outlined in the `mail()` manual. Otherwise, you may not receive it or it can also be treated as spam.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Full headers means having a valid `From` email address.

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You should also create an SPF record, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework